# How to perform customized bean mapping using Spring Bean Utils

Tags: spring-bean

**i am using Spring Bean Utils and want to copy data from A bean to another
B. the two beans are similar except some of the fields named as Bean DTO
and other as Bean Temp and are of different package.**

e.g

```
Class A{                         
 String name;
 BeanTemp bean;
}

Class B{
String name;
BeanDTO bean; 
}
```

> does Spring Bean utils provide customized way to map these two
>   different members if not then what is the way to map them.

please advise.

Thanks